# Registering DI for net7 function applications

Tags: c#, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

Registering services / classes via DI seemed straight forward with previous versions of .net core through to .net6 when creating fucntion apps. Normally i would create a startup.cs and initialize the startup by using `[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]` and then add my DI configuration such as `builder.Services.AddTransient<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();`
Then inject via constructor.

However .net6 and .net7 uses program.cs. I can add the startup.cs in .net6 and works fine but in .net7 its failing to initialize.

Q. Is there a way to register my dependencies using the program.cs or is there is a way to register a separate file such as startup.cs from program.cs to create separation?

Whats the advice on DI registration in .net7 for function apps?

Might of answered my own question here; to register in program using `HostBuilder.ConfigureServices`. But is it possible to register the startup / other config files for separation purposes though?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to register my dependencies using the program.cs or is there is a way to register a separate file such as startup.cs from program.cs to create separation?

***Using Startup.cs:***

***Way1:***

I have tried to configure the DI in `Startup.cs`.

Right click on the `Startup.cs` file and select `Properties`.

Change the Build Action to `Content` and `Output Directory` to `Copy always/Copy if newer`.

[image]

***`Startup.cs` file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using FunctionApp1;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Startup: FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddOptions();
        }
    }
}
```

But unable to hit the `Startup.cs` class.

Way 2 worked for me .

***Way 2:***

If you want to register in a separate file, follow as shown below.

***Using `Startup.cs` file***

***`Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var mystartup = new Startup();        
        mystartup.ConfigureServices(services);
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

- Generate a new Startup file.

[image]

***My `Startup.cs` file:***

```cs
using FunctionApp1.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<Test1, TsetResult>();      
    }
}
```

Yes, the dependency Injection in `.NET 7` can be done within the  `Program.cs` file itself.

***Using `Program.cs`:***

```cs
using FunctionApp1.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddTransient<Test1, TsetResult>();
    })
    .Build();
host.Run();
```

[image]